# Filtering - Multiple choices jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, filter

I am trying to create a filtering script that helps me to search for a specific thing. I am not that great with javascript / jquery and i found the following script and changed it the way i like it.

Everything worked fine, i could select white chicken, but the problem is when i select white and black to search all the animals that are white and black it doens't work.

what am i doing wrong or what can i change to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/2/

Javascript:

```
  $(function(){
  $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
  {
var $lis = $('.results > li'),
$checked = $('input:checked');
if ($checked.length)
{
    var selector = $checked.map(function ()
    {
        return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
    }).get().join('');

    $lis.hide().filter(selector).show().addClass("show");     
}
else
{
    $lis.show().removeClass("show");
}
});


})
```

Html:

```
<div class="tags">
 <fieldset class="filter-grp">
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="white" name="year" /> white </label><br>
 <label><input type="checkbox" rel="blue" name="year" /> blue </label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="yellow" name="year" /> yellow </label><br>
</fieldset>

<br>
<fieldset class="filter-grp">
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="horse" name="type"  /> horse</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="chicken" name="type"  /> chicken</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" rel="cow" name="type"  /> cow</label><br>
</fieldset>
<br>


</div>

<ul class="results">
<li class="white cow">white cow</li>
<li class="white horse">white horse</li>
<li class="white chicken">white chicken</li>
<li class="black cow">white cow</li>
<li class="blue horse">white horse</li>
<li class="white chicken">white chicken</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: But where is *black* option in your code?

Comment: i changed it to english words so u could understand, but forgot some things.. like the options hehe sorry i'm going to change it now

Comment: If you use default `join` you get more selections.  Is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/3/

Comment: yes this is excactly what i ment, thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem now is that if i select white, blue and horse it comes up with every animal that is white or blue it doesn't filter only horse out.. http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/9/ you can see it over here.

Comment: To be more specific: the Problem at the moment is that if i select a color and an animal it doesn't filter the things i selected. it shows multiple animals and colors and i don't understand why it does that.

You can check it over here ( select a color and a animal )
http://jsfiddle.net/d6Zyr/9/

Answer (score 0):

change to below script would help.
call join method as join('') which will help to create and case for multiple classes.

`join()` . => creates class and `.white,.horse` because `,` is addded as default.

`join('')` . => would create class as `.white.horse` and that what you want I suppose.

```
 $(function(){
      $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
      {
    var $lis = $('.results > li'),
    $checked = $('input:checked');
    if ($checked.length)
    {
        var selector = $checked.map(function ()
        {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show().addClass("show");     
    }
    else
    {
        $lis.show().removeClass("show");
    }
    });
```